# How should I approach the issue that bans do not persist after ending the monerod process?

Tags: daemon, nodes, peer, ban

I've been manually banning peers that are (a) clogging up my logs and (b) taking away space that would otherwise be used for legitimate `in_peer` connections (which I have limited for data usage reasons).  It is a little time consuming, but it's fine.  It does the job.

I didn't realize that closing `monerod` would discard that ban list.  My logs had been clearing up, and then I had to briefly shut down `monerod`.  Now I've got a sea of bad peers to manually ban again.

1. Is there a way to make the ban list persist?
2. If not within `monerod`, what might another (simple) strategy be to "preserve" that state?
3. Am I stuck having to write some script to detect IPs for auto-banning according to my rules? Perhaps by parsing the daemon log and sending a `ban` RPC command to the daemon?

I like the idea of learning new things, so if #3 is required, then so be it.  I just don't want to overcomplicate things if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

1) Not that I know of.

2) & 3) One way would be to make use of the built-in `monerod` commands and a little scripting. E.g.

```
monerod bans | awk  'NR>2 {print $1}' > bans.txt
```

Gets a list of any currently banned IPs. After you have restarted `monerod`, you could then:

```
cat bans.txt | while read ip; do monerod ban "$ip"; done
```

Which will re-ban them all.

If you want to permanently ban them though, I would add them to your firewall instead. I.e. block via iptables rules.